# spring batch: job status completed but no data committed when using SyncTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Here is my job structure.

```
<bean id="ControlJob" class="com.example.batch.ControlJob">
<property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
<property name="name" value="Outter job" />
<property name="moduleId" value="d" />
<property name="jobList">
  <list>
    <ref bean="a" />
    <ref bean="b" />
    <ref bean="c" />
    <ref bean="d" />
    <ref bean="e" />
    <ref bean="f" />
    <ref bean="g" />
    <ref bean="h" />
  </list>
</property>
<property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="syncTaskExecutor" />
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="syncTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor" />
```

---

This is my entrance:

```
public class SimpleJobLauncher {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] path = {"classpath:com/context.xml"};
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(path);
    context.registerShutdownHook();

    IBatchJobControllerBO batch = (IBatchJobControllerBO) context.getBean("batchJobControllerBO");
    //IBatchJobControllerBO batch = (IBatchJobControllerBO) context.getBean("synchronizedBatchJobControllerBO");
    try {
        BatchJobExecution execution = batch.startBatchJob("Outter job");
        //BatchJobExecution execution = batch.startBatchJob("Outter job");
        String message = execution.getExitMessage();
        System.out.println("job completed: " + message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

---

Two different bo to run the Outter job:

```
<bean id="batchJobControllerBO"
    class="com.bo.impl.BatchJobControllerBOImpl">
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
    <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobConfigurationRegistry" />
    <property name="batchJobDAO" ref="batchJobDAO" />
    <property name="batchJobExecutionDAO" ref="batchJobExecutionDAO" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="taskExecutor">
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />
    </property>
</bean> 

<bean id="synchronizedBatchJobControllerBO" parent="batchJobControllerBO" 
    class="com.bo.impl.BatchJobControllerBOImpl">
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="synchronizeJobLauncher" />
</bean>

<bean id="synchronizeJobLauncher" parent="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="taskExecutor">
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

---

Each job a ~ h is working perfectly and for the Outter Job if i use jobLauncher : "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" to call the Outter Job, it will work fine.

But when I use jobLauncher : "SyncTaskExecutor" to call the Outter Job, some of the job (the error is not stable) didn't commit any data to DB (the table is empty).

The job status is completed without any error.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this scenario?

Comment: Read tag description: `BATCH-FILE` **Does not** mean processing many files!

Comment: Thank you for your correct.

Comment: It's ok, make sure you also teach others to not make this mistake.